# how to Add Route to my login page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've created react project and I'm unable to think of a way to add my Login page route inside my `BrowserRouter` . Here's my `App.tsx`  file,

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import DashboardHome from "./pages/DashBoardPage/DashboardHome";
import MyAccount from "./pages/MyAccount/MyAccount";
import MyCourse from "./pages/MyCourse/MyCourse";
import Support from "./pages/Support/Support";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar/Sidebar";
import TopBar from "./topbar/TopBar";
import TeachersList from "./pages/TeachersList/TeachersList";
import PaymentsUI from "./pages/PaymentsUI/PaymentsUI";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="page-body overflow-hidden flex flex-col w-full h-screen">
        <TopBar />
        <div className="containerNew flex flex-1 overflow-hidden w-screen">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="other-section flex flex-1 overflow-y-auto ml-5">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/myCourse" component={MyCourse} />
              <Route path="/Support" component={Support} />
              <Route path="/MyAccount" component={MyAccount} />
              <Route path="/TeachersList/:index" component={PaymentsUI} />
              <Route path="/TeachersList" component={TeachersList} />
              <Route path="/" exact component={DashboardHome} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For now app only display `DashboardHome`

Login Route path is `<Route path="/login" component={LogIn}>` I need to add it as a complete screen, If I add it inside my `Switch` It'll only render inside my `other-section` div

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Login Route path is, ```<Route path="/login" component={LogIn}>``` I need to add it as a complete screen, If I add it inside my ```Switch``` It'll only render inside my ```other-section``` div

Answer (score 0):

You can try nesting of routes. Documentation reference : [Docs Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting)

Thus, you can try something like =>

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import DashboardHome from "./pages/DashBoardPage/DashboardHome";
import MyAccount from "./pages/MyAccount/MyAccount";
import MyCourse from "./pages/MyCourse/MyCourse";
import Support from "./pages/Support/Support";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar/Sidebar";
import TopBar from "./topbar/TopBar";
import TeachersList from "./pages/TeachersList/TeachersList";
import PaymentsUI from "./pages/PaymentsUI/PaymentsUI";
import LogIn from "path_of_your_component";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="page-body overflow-hidden flex flex-col w-full h-screen">
        <TopBar />
        <div className="containerNew flex flex-1 overflow-hidden w-screen">
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
          <Route path = "/login" exact component={Login}/>
          <Route path = "other-section" exact render = {
           ()=>
             (
                <div className="other-section flex flex-1 overflow-y-auto ml-5">
                 <Switch>
                   <Route path="/myCourse" component={MyCourse} />
                   <Route path="/Support" component={Support} />
                   <Route path="/MyAccount" component={MyAccount} />
                   <Route path="/TeachersList/:index" component={PaymentsUI} />
                   <Route path="/TeachersList" component={TeachersList} />
                   <Route path="/" exact component={DashboardHome} />
                 </Switch>
               </div>
             )
          </Switch>
          }/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```